# How to remove elements that directly contain a string - ignoring child elements

Tags: javascript, html, indexof, children

I am trying to work out how to remove elements on a page that contain a certain string using plain JavaScript.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body > *");
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    var current = elements[i];

    if (current.innerHTML.indexOf("Word") !== -1) {
        current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
    }
}
```

This is able to remove elements that contain the phrase "word". However, it digs down into a divs child nodes and returns true if the children contain the string.

How could I change this so that it checks if an element directly contains the string and ignores the children whilst searching the current element.

The code should still search every element but just not go into the child nodes.

**Does not return -1 (Returns true to containing the word):**

```
<div>Word</div>

<p>Word</p>
```

**Does return -1 (Returns false to containing the word):**

```
<div><p>Word</p></div>

<div><div>Word</div></div>
```

Would really appreciate any help with this, thank you!

Comment: "word" != "Word"

Comment: @forrestmid Whoops, updated!

Comment: Is plain js a requirement? it would be easier if you use jquery.

Comment: @KshitijMittal Yep, should be in plain JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var word = "Word"
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body > *");
function removeContainingText(element) {
  var children = Array.from(element.childNodes)
  for (var i = 0; i<children.length; ++i){
    if (children[i].nodeType == 3){
        if (children[i].nodeValue.indexOf(word) !== -1) {
            children[i].parentNode.removeChild(children[i]);
        }
    }
  }
}
for (var k = 0; k < elements.length; ++k){
    removeContainingText(elements[k])   
}
```

Comment: Try this, just change the value of word at the top to the one which you need to remove.

Comment: Thank you for this! I got it to work by replacing `body > *` with just `*` - It didn't seem to work with the `body >` part

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the childNodes of an element, filtering specifically for the text nodeType and looking for  Because whitespace can cause empty text nodes, run a trim as part of the test.

```
function containsText(element) {
  return Array.from(element.childNodes)
  .some(n=>n.nodeType === 3 && n.textContent.trim().length);
}
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

We can take this basic element "contains text" logic and modify it to support your specific test:

```
function containsText(text, element) {
  return Array.from(element.childNodes)
  .some(n=>n.nodeType === 3 && n.textContent.indexOf(text) !== -1);
}
```

And then use it as a condition inside your loop:

```
if (containsText('Word', current)) {
  current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this! Though how could I implement this in my code?

Comment: Updated with examples specific to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body > *");
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    var current = elements[i];

    if(current.children.length > 0){
        continue;
    }

    if (current.innerHTML.indexOf("Word") !== -1) {
        current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
    }
}
```